# Git fetch/pull only work when connected to a specific wifi?

Tags: git, wifi, fetch, pull

I've cloned a Git repository a few days back and began working on it, all the while on a wifi connection we'll call `wifi_a`.

Sometimes, `wifi_a` is unresponsive, but `wifi_b` generally works when `wifi_a` doesn't.  So, some days I use `wifi_b` instead.  Today was one of those days.

I decided I wanted to fetch recent updates utilizing the upstream remote.  However, fetch just hung there.  I then decided to try a pull.  Nothing.  All I got, after sitting here for minutes, was:

> fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
>   github.com[0: 207.97.227.239]: errno=Operation timed out

So, out of curiosity, I checked to see if `wifi_a` worked again.  It did!  So, I switched back to `wifi_a`.  I tried the git fetch again and it worked instantly!

My question now is.. why?  Why can't I be on a different wifi connection?  I was able to use my web browser while connected to `wifi_b` while I waiting for git to either finish the fetch or time out, so it's not that I wasn't connected.  I just find this behavior strange, and any explanation would really help.  After all, if I ever need to do some work but `wifi_a` is down, I'm hosed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still unsure why `wifi_b` isn't working.  The University owns before connections, but `wifi_b` isn't secured by any password.  My only guess is that since I created the fork using `wifi_a`, it only let's me do things with it while on `wifi_a`.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on who owns the wifi connections and what their policies are.  Most likely, the owners of `wifi_b` are blocking ssh connections.

Comment: One way to test this would be to connect to `wifi_b` and attempt to SSH into some other known working system (such as sdf.org -- you don't need an account to attempt the connection). If SSH is blocked, you can try using the Git protocol (though likely also blocked), or HTTPS.

Comment: Both wifis are owned by the university I'm at.  However, `wifi_a` is the student wifi (secured, requires password to use) and `wifi_b`, the one that doesn't work for Git, is their open wifi for anyone.  Weird though, because I can SSH into our servers on either wifi connection.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue.SSH on git doesn't work from my home wiffi network.But it does work on Mobile hotspot.Have found the solution for it ?

Comment: Hi @Saurabh47g -- i have exactly the same as you. Any chance you solved it and remember the solution? :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same symptoms.  I resolved it by tweaking the TCP/IP settings and turning off "Auto Proxy Detection"